# Finding a path to target object in nested array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, depth-first-search

I'm currently working through a problem that I'm having some trouble figuring out where I need to find a child node in an array of objects. The target could be one or many levels deep.

The issue is, once I find the object, I also need to push the path I took to get to that object into the resulting data array.

Currently, I have written code that can successfully find the child node:

```
const buildFullTree = (tree, cat, data = []) => {
  let collection = [tree]

  while (collection.length) {
    let node = collection.shift()

    if (node.id === cat.id) {
      data.push(node)
    }

    collection.unshift(...node.children)
  }

  return data
}
```

However, this isn't sufficient in terms of getting the path taken to that object.

I'm pretty sure that I need to change this to a recursive depth-first search solution in order to achieve what I'm looking for, but I am not sure how to change the while loop to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then perhaps you could revise your path search function like so to achieve what you require:

```js
const buildFullTree = (departmentTree, category, data = []) => {

  const findPath = (node, category) => {

    //If current node matches search node, return tail of path result
    if (node.id === category.id) {
      return [node]

    } else {

      //If current node not search node match, examine children. For first 
      //child that returns an array (path), prepend current node to that 
      //path result
      for (const child of node.children) {
        const childPath = findPath(child, category)
        if (Array.isArray(childPath)) {
          childPath.unshift(child)
          return childPath
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const foundPath = findPath(departmentTree, category)

  // If search from root returns a path, prepend root node to path in
  // data result
  if (Array.isArray(foundPath)) {
    data.push(departmentTree)
    data.push(...foundPath)
  }

  return data
}

const departmentTree = {
  id: 5,
  title: 'department',
  level: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 1,
    parentId: 5,
    title: 'category',
    level: 2,
    children: [{
      id: 15,
      parentId: 1,
      title: 'subcategory',
      level: 3,
      children: []
    }, {
      id: 18,
      parentId: 1,
      level: 3,
      title: 'subcategory',
      children: []
    }, {
      id: 26,
      parentId: 1,
      level: 3,
      title: 'subcategory',
      children: [{
        id: 75,
        parentId: 26,
        level: 4,
        title: 'sub-subcategory',
        children: []
      }, {
        id: 78,
        parentId: 26,
        level: 4,
        title: 'sub-subcategory',
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    id: 23823,
    title: 'category',
    level: 2,
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 9,
    parentId: 5,
    level: 2,
    title: 'category',
    children: [{
      id: 48414,
      parentId: 9,
      level: 3,
      title: 'subcategory',
      children: []
    }, {
      id: 2414,
      parentId: 9,
      level: 3,
      title: 'subcategory',
      children: []
    }, {
      id: 42414,
      parentId: 9,
      level: 3,
      title: 'subcategory',
      children: [{
        id: 2323213,
        parentId: 42414,
        level: 4,
        title: 'sub-subcategory',
        children: []
      }, {
        id: 322332,
        parentId: 42414,
        level: 4,
        title: 'sub-subcategory',
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

console.log('Path to 2323213:',
  buildFullTree(departmentTree, {
    id: 2323213
  }).map(node => node.id).join(' -> '))

console.log('Path to 23823:',
  buildFullTree(departmentTree, {
    id: 23823
  }).map(node => node.id).join(' -> '))

console.log('Path to -1 (non existing node):',
  buildFullTree(departmentTree, {
    id: -1
  }).map(node => node.id).join(' -> '))
```

Comment: Yes-that's exactly it! That did it! Thank you very much :D.

Comment: I'm curious if there's a way to refactor findPath to not have to have the category returned in an array, but it's fine the way it is.

Comment: that would depend on how you need your `path`  represented/returned. It would be possible to return the path as a string of ids in the form: `5 , 9 , 42414 , 2323213 , 2323213` - does that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine.

Comment: Also a question. I see we're returning an empty array on a match. Is this to facilitate the logic inside of the for loop? The way I read this, it essentially has builds a path through the children until a match is found. When the match is found, we give back an empty array that childpath can then unshift children into, thus giving us back the desired path. Just wanted to make sure that was the case.

Comment: hi, on match the a non-empty array is returned (it has the current node in it: `return [node]`). Here is a jsFiddle with the revised function returning a string of id's for the path: https://jsfiddle.net/g80zqu3v/ hope that helps

Comment: Ah right, I dunno why I thought it was empty. But that would still be what's going on, right? Once the match happens, there's now a call stack with a path that was taken to that array, so into that array we keep unshifting the path and returning the array until the call stack is empty.

Comment: yep that's pretty much it

Comment: Extremely clever and I was hoping to arrive at a solution that involved the call stack being leveraged. I think what I was missing was considering using an empty array as a base case for the recursive calls.

I learned a ton from this. Thank you very much.